# objdump full of zeroes

Tags: linux, objdump

The objdump of my binary returns a lot of functions that seem correct, but then there is a field of functions like this:

```
08c0ee1c <qglMateriali>:
 8c0ee1c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

08c0ee20 <qglEvalCoord1f>:
 8c0ee20:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

08c0ee24 <qglNormal3i>:
 8c0ee24:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

08c0ee28 <qglDeleteTextures>:
 8c0ee28:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

08c0ee2c <qglTexSubImage1D>:
 8c0ee2c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

08c0ee30 <qglMap2d>:
 8c0ee30:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...
```

It of course makes no sense that all those functions have 2 bytes that are all zeroes. Looking at the addresses with gameconqueror there is actual content to these functions. Why does objdump just have zeroes? Can I fix this?

Comment: So are you seeing a problem or just wondering why you see what you do?

Comment: @rholmes Well isn't it a problem that the objdump doesn't match the real memory in the process?

Comment: You may want to provide details on your environment and toolchain so someone can try to make more sense of it...

Comment: Also perhaps command line invocation and relevant info on functions and modules...